# How to set back pages per sheet permanently in Evince printer setup?

Tags: printing, evince

I use Evince for viewing PDFs. Usually I print 2 pages in 1 sheet, so I set this in the `Print->Preferences` window. After I clicked `OK` then `Print`, the papers comming out and I close the program. The problem is that the program remembers to this setting, so next time when somebody will use the program his printings will be unintentionally contain 2 pages in 1 sheet too.

[image: the problem in the Preferences window]

This behavior is totally unexpected, because other programs reset these settings after the prorgam is closed. I tried to go back to the `Preferences` and set back the number to 1 but despite I clicked `OK` Evince forgets the changes if I click on `Cancel` in the Print window.

For setting back permanently, I have to print an empty page or start to print something than cancel the print in progress.

Is this a bug? Are there an acceptable solution to this problem?

Comment: The dialog title seems to suggest that you changed your HP LaserJet's default preferences and not those of Evince, and so it affects others too. See if Evince has its own pages per sheet option you can modify.

Comment: @Karan It can't be the printer, because changing the settings only affect Evince. If I start other programs and watch the settings, they are the default. Also there aren't specific settings neither in the printer or in Evince to the other...

Comment: Does Evince have a forum you can report this on? Perhaps that "Quick Sets" option I see above can help in creating different sets of printing preferences? That way you might be able to use your custom settings, while others can use the defaults.

Comment: @Karan I tried Quick Sets too, but they are useless because of the same problem: Evince saves them only if I click to print. The reason why I always need the default setting at start is that a whole family uses the computer and I can't tell everybody to always check the settings because some of them are not really familiar with computers or they just forget it in their hurry.